# How to get Nested formgroup's controls in angular

Tags: angular

> https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#controls

Follwing my form:

```
this.form= this.fb.group({
  id: ['', [Validators.required]],
  name: ['', [Validators.maxLength(500)]],
  child: this.fb.group({
    id: [ '', [Validators.required]],
    name: ['']
  })
});
```

I want to get the validity of child, like `this.form.controls.child.controls.valid`, while `.controls` renturn AbstractControl  refer to this formgroup api.

angular compile error, error TS2339: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You are close. See code example below or play with it on the very simple (and ugly) StackBlitz I created.

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-basics-winjqw)

**In your template be sure to add your child form group.**

```html
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="send()">
    <input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name">
    <div formGroupName="child">
       <input type="text" name="id" formControlName="id">
       <input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">send</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Then in your component you can access the fields like so.

`this.myForm['controls'].child['controls'].id.valid`

The reactive form I created for this example:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.maxLength(500)]],
      child: this.fb.group({
        id: ['', [Validators.required]],
        name: ['']
      })
    });
```

## **Update Dec 2019**

My original answer is a bit dated. There is now a much cleaner way of accomplishing this! Below is example code of the cleaner solution.

`this.myForm.get('child.id').valid`

Comment: Thanks,my template is the same as yours.I can get the controls of `child` in chrome, while compile error in ide. error TS2339: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

Comment: Ah yes, that is a nasty Angular bug. see updated answer, use `this.myForm['controls'].child['controls'].id.valid` instead

Comment: Great!You are right.Then I found another way to solve the qestion , convert `this.form.controls.child`'s type to FormGroup.

Comment: Awesome, glad that worked. Also, that is a slick solution too! You should update your question to be more specific about the error you were needing to solve so anyone else running into your problem will find the solution. It’s a bit vague the way it’s written now and it is a very valid question.

Comment: how to perform setvalidators function to those nested formgroup items.

Comment: @Narm your answer generates this error with noImplicitAny: true in the typescript compiler `error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'AbstractControl' has no index signature.
`

Comment: @Narm thank you so much I was searching for such solution but couldn't find any

Comment: @Narm i have some issue in angular nested form control can you fix it this is my question link thank for giving me time                                                              https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59324879/i-am-using-formarray-and-i-have-controls-inside-another-controls-but-how-can-i-a

Comment: There is no reference to the loop for the nested controls in this answer.

Answer (score 30):

There are a couple of very simple ways to access the FormControl in a nested FormGroup. From the AbstractControl usage notes:

> ### Retrieve a nested control
>
> For example, to get a name control nested within a person sub-group:
>
> this.form.get('person.name');
>
> -OR-
>
> this.form.get(['person', 'name']);

Comment: Link to the Angular docs for reference: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get

Answer (score 12):

```
userForm=new FormGroup({
    fName:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    lName:new FormControl(),
    eMail:new FormControl('',[Validators.email,Validators.required]),
    qualificationForm:new FormGroup({
     perS:new FormControl(''),
     perHs:new FormControl('')
    })
});

save(){
  console.log(this.userForm.get("qualificationForm.perS").value);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

One way I use alot is to cast the child `FormGroup` to a `FormGroup` as the 'get('control')' method returns an `AbstractControl` and then use the 'get()' method to access the child `FormGroup` options like so :

```
(this.form.get('child') as FormGroup).get('id').valid
```

Answer (score 6):

I have the following form:

```
registerLibrarianForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(128), Validators.pattern(this.nameRegex)]],
       lastName:  ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(128), Validators.pattern(this.nameRegex)]],
       address: this.formBuilder.group({
         country: ['', [Validators.required]],
         city: ['', [Validators.required]]})})
```

The way I get the controls of the main form (registerForm) is by creating a simple return method:

```
get controls(){
return this.registerForm.controls;
}
```

And the way I get the controls of the nested form (address) is by creating another method:

```
get addressControls(){
return ((this.registerForm.get('address') as FormGroup).controls)
}
```

So if you need to do a *ngIf in the HTML for the main form use first method

```
*ngIf="controls.firstName.errors && ...
```

And for the nested form:

```
*ngIf="addressControls.country.errors && ...
```

I hope this might help!