# i am using FormArray and i have controls inside another controls but how can i add element in nested controls in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

i am little confuse about push data into control because i using control inside nested control i have no idea how i push data inside the nested control 
this is my component.ts code

```
 mileStoneForm:FormGroup;
 constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {
 this.mileStoneForm = this.fb.group({
  milestone:this.fb.array([])
 });


  createMilestone()
  {
  return this.fb.group({
    name:[''],
    date:[''],
    description:[''],
    value:[''],
    approval:[''],
    deliverable:this.fb.array([
      this.createMilestoneDeliverable()
    ])
  });
 }


   createMilestoneDeliverable()
  {
  return this.fb.group({
    title:[''],
    description:[''],
    excluded:['']
  });
 }


addNewDeliverable()
 {
return (this.mileStoneForm.get('milestone').get('deliverable') as 
FormArray).controls.push(this.createMilestoneDeliverable());
 }
```

this add function is used to store data in deliverable field i want to push 
this.createMilestoneDeliverable() function data into deliverable field 
help me guys i am so confuse i can not fix it with myself

Comment: Can this help you `return (this.mileStoneForm.get(['milestone','deliverable']) as 
FormArray).push(this.createMilestoneDeliverable());` ?

Comment: @Ashot Aleqsanyan    when i am adding new row into deliverable it,s give me this erro in console ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null

Comment: Hello Please can you include the `createMilestone` function call and  `mileStoneForm ` form in your question

Comment: I see updated answer and in your current example you have not any `deliverable` in your form and your `milestone ` is the formArray instead of formGroup

Comment: can you refine my code and comment it to me

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example, Please check the link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ou6dje