# How to get the value of nested form with get in formbuilder?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-formbuilder

I use form builder to build a form and using ***get*** to obtain the value of birthday, ageNum and ageUnit, but it seems that this method is not working cuz it may got ***null*** in group age.
does anyone know how to fix this? thanks

**ts**

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      birthday: ['', this.validateDate],
      age: this.fb.group(
        [
          {
            ageNum: [],
            ageUnit: [AgeUnit.Year]
          },
          {validator: this.validateAge('ageNum', 'ageUnit')}
        ])
    })

    const birthday = this.form.get('birthday');
    const ageNum = this.form.get('age').get('ageNum');   //here got wrong
    const ageUnit = this.form.get('age').get('ageUnit'); //and here
```

**html**

```
<div [formGroup]="form" class="age-input">
  <div>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input type="text" matInput [matDatepicker]="birthPicker" formControlName="birthday" placeholder="birthDate">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="birthPicker" matSuffix></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-error>date error</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-datepicker touchUi="true" #birthPicker></mat-datepicker>
  </div>

  <ng-container formGroupName="age">
    <div class="age-num">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input type="number" placeholder="age" matInput formControlName="ageNum">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div>
      <mat-button-toggle-group formControlName="ageUnit" [(ngModel)]="selectedUnit">
        <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let unit of ageUnits" [value]="unit.value">
          {{unit.label}}
        </mat-button-toggle>
      </mat-button-toggle-group>
    </div>
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('age').hasError('ageInvalid')">age or unit error</mat-error>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show `component.html` file ?

Comment: Okay, I just posted it, thank you for remind me this.

Comment: I think that it need to you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/formbuilder?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: 1.**not** use ngModel and formControlName in the same tag, 2.remove the `[` and `]` when create the formGroup -unless you want a formArray-.3.- (optional) you can use "dot notation": `const ageNum = this.form.get('age.ageNum')`

Answer (score 0):

In short, you could try following syntax for getting the value of a FormControl inside a FormGroup:

```
const ageNum = this.form.get(['age', 'ageNum']).value;
const ageUnit = this.form.get(['age', 'ageUnit']).value;
```

However, a similar question has already been answered, go there for more possiblities and details: [How to get Nested formgroup's controls in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49269403/how-to-get-nested-formgroups-controls-in-angular)